# Working with node js and angular js

Tags: node.js

I am just trying out node js and angular js. here is my node code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var sys = require('sys');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
fs.readFile('angularjsex.html',function (err, data){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Content-Length':data.length});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
});
}).listen(8000);
```

The angularjsex.html file:

```
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <hr>
    <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The angular js just does not work. Am i missing something?

Comment: What is the result that you get ? What is the result expected ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning the contents of the file `angularjsex.html` for every request. In your HTML file, there's a reference to `angular.js` that the browser will try to load from your server, and that request will get the same (HTML!) contents.

For a solution that works with your current server app, replace this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
```

With this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

But I would suggest to start using [Express](http://expressjs.com/), in which case you can leave the HTML code as is if you change your server to this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(8000);
```

Create a directory `public` and place your `angularjsex.html` and `angular.js` files into it. To view the result, open `http://localhost:8000/angularjsex.html` in your browser.

To install Express:

```
npm install express
```